# UIView animate withDuration does not call the completion handler on iOS 9.3.5

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, animation, uiview

I have this animation block

```
  UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: { 
            self.holdingView.alpha = .5
        }, completion: { (complete) in
            if complete {
                self.holdingView.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        })
    }
```

But for whatever reason the completion handler is never called on iphones and itouches running iOS 9.3.5 but oddly enough it's called on an iPad Mini running iOS 9.3.5.

This has been very difficult to debug because i don't get any errors in the console. Additionally the completion handler is called onall iOS versions > 9.3.5

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the issue that the completion handler isn't called or the `complete` property isn't `true`?

Comment: Write a print statement, something like `print("completion executed", complete)` right under/after `(complete) in`, and outside your `if complete { ... }` block. The print statement will 1. Print the "completion executed" text and 2. will give you the value of `complete`. If `complete` is false then it means that your animation was not completed, therefore not triggering the code inside your if statement.

Comment: You need to be on the main thread so my guess is you are calling this from a background thread.

Comment: @rmaddy the completion handler isn't called. i've set break points in the animation closure and that runs fine, and breakpoints in the completion handler but it never hits that point. Another thing that's odd is that this issue seems very device & OS specific. Everything works fine on any device running iOS higher than 9, and works fine on an iPads running iOS 9. but this issue is only present in iPhones and iTouch running iOS 9.3.5. was wondering if this was known issue.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in Simulator also?

Comment: Yes @shallowThought

Comment: Are you using Swift4?

Comment: no @shallowThought i am not.

Comment: Same. Any progress?

Answer (score 0):

I just faced a similar problem. I was animating my view in a **serial** way.
I guess the completionHandler was trying to connect to the previous animation. I removed all animations as follows and all went well.

In your case, try the following:

```
self.holdingView.layer.removeAllAnimations()
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: { 
            self.holdingView.alpha = .5
        }, completion: { (complete) in
            if complete {
                self.holdingView.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        })
    }
```